# Proof of transitivity of an equivalence relation on $\Bbb{N}$ x $\Bbb{N}$

Tags: proof-verification, equivalence-relations

I have to prove this equivalence relation. I think I have down reflexivity and symmetry. But I am stuck on transitivity. Any kind of help would be helpful.

Define a relation ~ on $ \Bbb{N}$  x  $\Bbb{N}$ as follows. For any $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ in $\Bbb{N}$, $(a,b)$ ~ $(c,d)$ if and only if $a + d = b  + c.$

Prove that ~ is an equivalence relation on $\Bbb{N}$ x $\Bbb{N}$

- You may not refer to, or use subtraction in any manner. You may on
  the other hand, assume that you have already proved the following.
  For any natural numbers $m$, $n$, and $k$, if $m+k=n+k$, then $m=n$

**Reflexivity**

We have to show that $(a,b)$ ~ $(a,b)$

Let $(a,b)$ be arbitrary elements of $\Bbb{N}$ x $\Bbb{N}$

We have
$a+b=b+a$

Since $a$ and $b$ are natural numbers, addition is commutative over natural numbers.

So, $a+b=b+a$ is true as desired.

Therefore, the relation is reflexive

**Symmetry**

We have to show that IF $(a,b)$ ~ $(c, d)$ THEN $(c,d)$ ~ $(a,b)$.

Let $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ be arbitrary elements of $\Bbb{N}$ x $\Bbb{N}$

Assume that $(a,b)$ ~ $(c, d)$.

We have $a+d=b+c.$

Since addition is commutative over natural numbers. We can write the expression as
$c+b=d+a$.

Which is equivalent to $(c,d)$ ~ $(a,b)$.

Therefore, the relation is symmetric.

**Transitivity**

We will have to show that IF $(a,b)$ ~ $(c,d)$ and $(c,d)$ ~ $(e,f)$ THEN $(a,b)$ ~ $(e,f)$.

Let $(a,b)$, $(c,d)$ and $(e,f)$ be arbitrary elements of $\Bbb{N}$ x $\Bbb{N}$

Asume that $(a,b)$ ~ $(c,d)$ and $(c,d)$ ~ $(e,f)$.

We have $(a+d)+(c+f)=(b+c)+(d+e)$

STUCK HERE

Comment: Hint: Rewrite both sides in the form $? + (c + d)$, and then use the cancellation law.

Comment: We have $a+d=b+c$ and $c+f=d+e$. And we want to prove that $a+f=b+e$. From the first two we have $(a+d)+(c+f)=(b+c)+(d+e)$. Thus $a+ (d+c)+f=b+(d+c)+e$.

Comment: Side note: I wrote a problem very similar to this one. May I ask where this comes from?

Comment: This problem is almost certainly inspired by a common construction of $\mathbb{Z}$ as the quotient space of this equivalence relation.  (And that, in turn, has been generalized to the "Grothendieck group" of a commutative monoid - though if the monoid is not integral (cancellative), you have to define the equivalence relation as $\exists x, a + d + x = b + c + x$.)

Answer (score 1):

This comment from the problem statement is key:

> You may not refer to, or use subtraction in any manner. You may on the other hand, assume that you have already proved the following. For any natural numbers $m$, $n$, and $k$, if $m+k=n+k$, then $m=n$.

Take what you have so far: $(a+d)+(c+f)=(b+c)+(d+e)$.

By associativity and commutativity of addition, you can write this as: $a+f+c+d=b+e+c+d$. Then, the comment from the problem essentially says, "You are allowed to cancel the "$+d$" from both sides, leaving: $a+f+c=b+e+c$.

Then, that comment again allows you to cancel the "$+c$" from both sides, leaving: $a+f=b+e$.

This is what you wanted to show, allowing you to conclude $(a,b)\sim(e,f)$.